# Quotename in Openquery

Tags: sql-server

I am using bcp to export query results to CSV file. The query works perfectly as below:

```
declare @sqlcmd varchar(6500)

set @sqlcmd='bcp "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServerName, '
           +'''SELECT [column1] FROM Hist '
           +'WHERE DateTime >= DateAdd(hh,-24,GetDate()) '
           +'AND DateTime <= GetDate()'')" '
           +'queryout C:\Temp.csv -T -c -t,'

exec xp_cmdshell @sqlcmd
```

After I added `quotename` function to column1, the below query doesn't work:

```
declare @sqlcmd varchar(6500)

set @sqlcmd='bcp "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServerName, '
           +'''SELECT quotename([column1]) FROM Hist '
           +'WHERE DateTime >= DateAdd(hh,-24,GetDate()) '
           +'AND DateTime <= GetDate()'')" '
           +'queryout C:\Temp.csv -T -c -t,'

exec xp_cmdshell @sqlcmd
```

Result:

```
Error Message Incorrect syntax near '('
```

I would appreciate it if anyone can give me some advise. Thanks

Comment: Try this `SELECT QUOTENAME('column1')`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the linked server may not have a `QUOTENAME` function. Perhaps it's not a SQL Server itself, or is older than SQL 2008?

Check what that server is, and the functions it can perform. Note that:

```
QUOTENAME([column1])
```

is equivalent to:

```
'[' + REPLACE(column1, ']', ']]') + ']'
```

I think most SQL variants will have some version of `REPLACE`.

UPDATE: Based on you comments, you actually wanted to format `column1` for inclusion in the CSV file, assuming it may have commas in it.

To do that, you need to put double quotes around the contents of `column1`, *and* replace any double quote characters in `column1` with two double quotes (which acts as an escape).

So, again, assuming that the destination server does have some form of the `REPLACE` function, you should be able to use:

```
'"' + REPLACE([column1], '"', '""') + '"'
```

An alternative:  If there's no equivalent to the `REPLACE` function on the remote server, you could try setting up an SSIS package to do the job. You can replace `column1` in the data flow with the above, using a Derived Column component. However, this is probably not a great option if you're not familiar with SSIS packages already.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to put quotename to Column1 is because it is a string with comma. I want to put double quotes around Column1 by using quotename so that it will not be separated to two cells once exported to csv file.I feel you are right the linked server doesn't have quotename function. Is there a way I can put a double quotes around column1 using other methods?

Comment: Updated to cover actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remind me, can you use column names and expressions instead of * in SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(...)

Then you could put a QUOTENAME(...) there.  Note that if your QUOTENAME() is the same as mine, it's designed for object names and it returns data type sysname which is basically nvarchar(128).  But QUOTENAME(expression, '"') should indeed turn The "Laurels", Sweetvillage into: "The ""Laurels"", Sweetvillage"

Have you looked at an approach of invoking SQLCMD utility instead of BCP?  I think BCP is dumb for issues like this, and SQLCMD may be a better tool for constructing a SQL query whose output is comma-separated text, even if you have to use QUOTENAME() on several columns.  For a character column that doesn't contain quote mark and commas it's probably optional.